# Invalid type in JSON write (__SwiftValue)

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4, swifty-json

I am trying to pass a Parameters [String:Any] value to JSONSerialization.data and it's throwing error every time.

I know the values of the [String:Any] dictionary is Swifty.JSON objects. But I am not able to convert them to NSDictionary object.

I populate the params from another dictionary like so:

```
var params = [String:Any]()
for (key, value) in self.myDictionary[self.selectedEntry] as! JSON {
    print("\(key) - \(value.description)")
    params[key]=value     
}
```

And this is whats inside the params object after a print(params).

```
["searchOptions": {
  "omit_saved_records" : false
}, "customFilters": {
  "is_next_sellers_search" : "Y"
}, "use_code_std": [
  "RSFR",
  "RCON"
]]
```

I am passing the params to this function:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted)
```

This is where the error occur.

I am expecting this to simply work but I get this error instead:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__SwiftValue)'

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use Codable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `JSON` type of `SwiftyJSON` is a custom type and cannot be serialized.

Just get the `dictionaryObject` from the `JSON` object

```
if let params = self.myDictionary[self.selectedEntry].dictionaryObject {
```

And don't `prettyPrint`. The server doesn't care

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params)
```

Note: You are encouraged to drop `SwiftyJSON` in favor of `Codable`.